# Hyundai Sonata not filling up with gas all the way after fuel pump replacement

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, gasoline, sonata, pump

So about two months ago I replaced the fuel pump in my 2012 Hyundai Sonata gls. When I picked it up and went to get gas it filled up to one bar below full and wouldn’t take anymore gas. For the last two months I’ve replaced the canister purge valve and charcoal canister and another part. Not sure why it’s still having the same issue and why it only started after replacing the fuel pump.

Comment: Do you continue to add fuel after the pump shuts off in an attempt to get the gauge to read full?

Comment: My 2014 has always done this at certain stations.